# Android: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting data from the API and then inserting that data into the SQLite database. But when I am inserting that data there is some issue. I am unable to find out that issue. 
I am getting the correct data from the API. No issue with that. Only issue is in inserting the data into the database.

**My Json Data Formate is:**

> {"sku":"T_010","product_id":"7","name":"footaball","thumbnail_image":"http://www.keyss.in/pos/magento/media/catalog/product/no_selection","description":null,"short_description":null,"weight":"0.0000","created_at":"2013-01-15 07:00:36","updated_at":"2013-01-15 07:00:36","price":"13.0000","special_price":null,"tax_class_id":"1","cat_id":["4","15"],"cat_name":{"4":"Mobile & Accessories","15":"Sports Fitness"}},

**My Main Class**

[Link to the Main class](http://pastebin.com/asQqyqEc)

**My ProductDbHandler class**
[Link to My database class](http://pastebin.com/RwxApQGm)

**class for Getter and Setter**     [Link to the Getter & Setter Class](http://pastebin.com/fpXP1AB1)
**My Logcat showing this:**

```
02-05 12:31:39.601: I/Database(274): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table tbProductDetails has no column named cat_id
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274): Error inserting cat_id=["5"] price=10.0 updated_at=null weight=1.0 product_id=1 tax_class_id=0 description=324354 thumbnail_image=http://www.keyss.in/pos/magento/media/catalog/product/no_selection name=assdfg created_at=2013-01-15 06:19:59 sku=T_001 special_price=12.0 cat_name={"5":"Cameras"}
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table tbProductDetails has no column named cat_id: , while compiling: INSERT INTO tbProductDetails(cat_id, price, updated_at, weight, product_id, tax_class_id, description, thumbnail_image, name, created_at, sku, special_price, cat_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at database.in.ProductDbHandler.addProducts(ProductDbHandler.java:64)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at com.hellovx100.in.ClerkLogin.getItemsOfDept(ClerkLogin.java:110)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at com.hellovx100.in.ClerkLogin.onCreate(ClerkLogin.java:92)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-05 12:31:39.621: E/Database(274):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where I am doing wrong please Guide me.

Any help is appriciated.

EDIT: I think the problem is with josn data formate which I am getting **"cat_id":["4","15"],"cat_name":{"4":"Mobile & Accessories","15":"Sports Fitness"}},** How can we parse this in json because it is like array inside an array. logcat also giving error at **02-05 12:31:39.601: I/Database(274): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table tbProductDetails has no column named cat_id**

How to deal with this kind of issue

Comment: Please uninstall your app on to device and run again.

Comment: also change ur database version ..

Comment: Ok @ManmeetSinghBatra and HCD I will try your suggestions

Comment: @HCD and Manmeet still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think here is your problem , you are missing a space.

instead of :

```
database.in.DatabaseAndTableNames.PRODUCT_DISCRIPTION_COLUMN+"TEXT,"
```

try

```
database.in.DatabaseAndTableNames.PRODUCT_DISCRIPTION_COLUMN+" TEXT,"
```

Comment: still not working. I think the problem is with cat_id":["4","15"] kind of json data. Logcat showing this 02-05 12:31:39.601: I/Database(274): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table tbProductDetails has no column named cat_id

Answer (score 0):

Post your create statement here..
Verify and be sure you are adding cat_id column,and specific datatype.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Aditi, do checkout the FAQ before posting anything. I'm afraid that I would have to downvote you for that is not an 'answer' to the question posted. Do edit your answer or you should have posted that as a comment.

Comment: @Roylee : I can not comment as I am not having that reputation.
But Thanks neway..

Answer (score -2):

02-05 11:13:09.993: I/Database(287): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tbProductDetails

first create the table then insert the data..

Comment: hey can you share ur db file . or check it db file through sqlite browser or firefox sqlite tool table is create or not. if it is created check the table properties